# Assigning / copying 1D vector to a 2D vector

Tags: c++, 2d-vector

I have loaded data from a text file in a 2D vector. I am extracting data column wise, finding min, max in every column and then normalizing it. Normalized data is stored in a separate temp vector, keeping in mind that i extracted data from column therefore it should go back to columns.
I need to reconstruct the original 2D vector back from the normalized individual temp vector.

```
 vector <vector<double> >loadedData;
 vector <double> normal;
 vector <double> temp;
 vector <vector <double> >normalDataFrom1D;
 normalDataFrom1D.resize(rows, vector<double>(cols,0.0));

 loadedData = net.loadData(file);
 int cols = net.no_of_cols("../sampleData.txt");
 int rows = net.no_of_rows("../sampleData.txt");

    for(int i=0;i<cols;i++){
      min = net.min_1d(i);
      max = net.max_1d(i);
      cout<<"Min val in Col ["<<i<<"] data :"<<min<<endl;
      cout<<"Max val in Col ["<<i<<"] data :"<<max<<endl;
      normal = net.extract_1d(i);
      temp = net.normalizeData_1d(normal, min, max);  

      for(int r=0;r<normalDataFrom1D.size();r++){
        for(int c=0;c<normalDataFrom1D[r].size();c++){
          normalDataFrom1D[c][r] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
//Printing Data...
    for(int r=0;r<normalDataFrom1D.size();r++){
      for(int c=0;c<normalDataFrom1D[r].size();c++){
        cout<<"Data in normalDataFrom1D["<<r<<"]["<<c<<"] = "<<normalDataFrom1D[r][c]<<endl;
      }
    }

error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<double>’ to ‘double’ in assignment
           normalDataFrom1D[c][r] = temp;
```

If i try:

```
temp[i].push_back(net.normalizeData_1d(normal, min, max));
```

It says:

```
error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘temp.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<double, std::allocator<double> >(((std::vector<double>::size_type)i))’, which is of non-class type ‘double’
       temp[i].push_back(net.normalizeData_1d(normal, min, max));
```

Comment: You are trying to assign vector to double. Usually people iterate vectors.

Comment: Oh yes, if i iterate then i get a Segmentation fault.

Comment: ...and that would be the landing place for your debugger.

Comment: Can anyone provide  a short code snippet for assignment / copying of 1D vector into 2D vector?

Comment: Why not just place it into a 2D temp vector instead of a 1D temp vector?